# Heroku error when connecting to its python instance: "Connection refused"

Tags: python, curl, heroku

The python starts successfully and the Heroku app is stuck in "listening on port 5000", as it should by this `server.py`:

```
(...)
parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, default=5000, help='port number')
parser.add_argument('--debug', action='store_true', help='enable debug mode')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.debug:
    app.debug = True

app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

This works and `heroku logs --tail` shows the app starting as expected. The app in heroku stays in "`Running on http://0.0.0.0:33507/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`"

However, when doing a curl to my heroku app like this `curl -X POST https://APPNAME.herokuapp.com/search -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "text": "some_text"}'` the application halts indefinetly

And when doing `curl -X POST https://APPNAME.herokuapp.com:5000/search -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "text": "some_text"}'` (notice I added the port in the url) I get

> (7) Failed to connect to APPNAME.herokuapp.com port 5000: Connection refused

Same if the port is passed as a flag `-p 5000`.

Does anyone know exactly why this is happening?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the port your application binds to is *not* the same as the port Heroku exposes to the internet for you. Heroku listens on http (port 80) and https (port 443) for you. So your curl command should omit the port from the URL.

Heroku's routing layer acts as a proxy to your application, which should bind the the port that is provided via the `$PORT` environment variable. But you cannot connect to that port directly (by extension, you can't connect to your application via any protocol other than HTTP).

In addition, there is a minor bug in the code you posted - `server.py` accepts a `--port` parameter, but you don't pass it to the `run()` method. You need to change it to `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=args.port)`. In addition, make sure the `Procfile` web process is defined as `web: python server.py --port $PORT`, so that you bind to the port that Heroku expects (which is not guaranteed to be port 5000).

Hope that helps.